# Stylus calling mixin inside selector doen'st work

Tags: css, stylus

I am trying to organize my code using Stylus mixin feature. Consider the code below:

```
.navbar
  height 82px
  background #ddd
  breakpoint(n.breakpoint) // mixin

// this is the mixin I used above.
breakpoint(value)
  @media ( max-width value)
    .navbar-header
        float none
    .navbar-toggle
        display block
    .navbar-collapse 
        border-top 1px solid transparent
        box-shadow inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1)

    .navbar-collapse.collapse 
        display none !important
    .navbar-nav 
        float none!important
        margin 7.5px -15px

    .navbar-nav
        > li 
            float none
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in
        display block !important
    .collapsing
        overflow hidden !important
```

Code compiles perfectly but this yields to:

```
.navbar{
   height: 82px;
   background: #ddd
 }
```

I am supposing it should include the mixin's code right after `.navbar` but where `breakpoint`'s styles are going?

Answer (score 0):

A mixin should be defined before it will be used. You need to move the mixin before `.navbar`.